# How to place a variable and plain text in the same column of the table in Haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

In my Haml code I would like to show a value with a currency code in the same column in a table, however every time I try I get error or the Haml engine places it outside the table:

```
%tr
      %td= pocket.address
      %td= pocket.deal
      %td= pocket.balance
      USD // I want include this text to the column above
      %td= link_to 'Show', wallets_show_path
```

In an ERB file it would look like this:

```
<%= pocket.balance %> USD
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `%td= "#{pocket.balance} USD"` ?

Comment: "[What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use string interpolation (without additional strings):

```
  %td #{pocket.balance} USD
```

or just use multiline syntax:

```
  %td
    = pocket.balance
    USD
```

PS. if your currency is fixed, better not hardcode it in views, make a `currency` method in whatever `pocket` is, it may return constant, but will be much easier to find later

Comment: If the currency is not fixed you want to place the whole thing in a helper method. `"#{pocket.balance} #{pocket.currency}"` breaks down as soon you get to GBP or Yen.

Answer (score 1):

Just use string interpolation.

```
%tr
  %td= pocket.address
  %td= pocket.deal
  %td= "#{pocket.balance} USD"
  %td= link_to 'Show', wallets_show_path
```

You could also pass a block:

```
%tr
  %td= pocket.address
  %td= pocket.deal
  %td 
    %span= pocket.balance
    %span= USD
  %td= link_to 'Show', wallets_show_path
```